# SQL : Group by and check if all, some or none are set

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate

Lets say I have the following table:

```
FKEY A B C D E F
'A'    1 0 1 0 1 0
'A'    0 1 1 1 0 0
```

Now i want to make a group by FKEY but I just want to know if the A-F columns has 1 in one, all or none of the grouped rows..  The resulton the above table would be:

```
FKEY A B C D E F
'A'  S S A S S N
```

..where S is "some", A is "all" and N is "none".

What would be the best approach to make this query. I could so some nested queries, but isnt there a smarter way?

In my real life data, the 1's and 0's are actually DATETIME and NULL's

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Well. as long as you're talking concepts, the specific database should not be relevant. I left it out on purpose because I ought to be able to translate any ansver into the specific DB I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` and aggregation:

```
select fkey,
       (case when sum(a) = 0 then 'N'
             when sum(a) = count(*) then 'A'
             else 'S'
        end) as a,
       (case when sum(b) = 0 then 'N'
             when sum(b) = count(*) then 'A'
             else 'S'
        end) as b,
       . . .
from t
group by fkey;
```

The above assumes that the values are only `0` and `1`.  If that is the case, you can actually phrase this as:

```
   (case when max(a) = 0 then 'N'
         when min(a) = 1 then 'A'
         else 'S'
    end) as a,
```

Comment: Yea..  I was propably a bit too vague in my question here, because its actually not booleans but dates and null.
But I propably could do a single subquery and make the date/nulls into 1 and 0..

Comment: You probably won't need to convert them if you use count(date) - to count(), nulls are worth 0, anything else is worth 1. Valid learning point though; always post your actual question, rather than a modified form of it

Comment: @HenrikClausen . . . That really doesn't change the first answer.  If you have a question about dates, though, and this doesn't quite apply, *ask a new question*.  This question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that your 0 and 1 are actually null or non null dates. Here's a modified version of Gordon's query that caters for that:

```
select fkey,
       (case when count(datecol) = 0 then 'all dates are null'
             when count(datecol) = count(*) then 'all dates are filled'
             else 'some are null, some filled'
        end) as a,
       ...
from t
group by fkey;
```

`COUNT(null)` is 0, `COUNT('2001-01-01')` is 1, `COUNT(*)` is the row count independent of any variable. Hence, if our count of the dates was 0, all must be null. If the count of the dates was equal to the count of the rows, then all must be filled with some value, otherwise it's a mix